# Performance test for converting cell array to numeric array conversion

Tags: performance, matlab, cell-array

```
Cell_in = {'a' '2,34' '3,45' '5,342';
           'b' '3,4' '5,5' '5,2';
           'c' '4' '3,9' '4,3';
           'd' '4,5' '5,7' '6,12';}
```

Cell_in just an example but in real the size is 300000 x 20. The data is in german format i.e 1,23 = 1.23 (English format). The first column is parameter and staring from second column till end is data. The first step is to extract data and then I replace ',' with '.' ,then convert it to double for signal processing.

```
Data_in = cell_in(:,2:end);
Data_in = strrep(Data_in,',','.');
Data_in = str2double(Data_in); % Step 1
```

And then after processing I convert the data back to german format by replacing '.' with ','

```
% signal Processing...

Data_out = arrayfun(@(x) num2str(x),Data_in,'uni',0); % Step 2
Data_out = strrep(Data_out,',','.');
% Save data to file...
```

The executing time for steps 1 and 2 are too long. Is there a better way to improve performance?

Comment: how do you end up having the data in this a large cell array? are you reading files from disk?

Comment: @daniel.wirtz Yes, I read the files from disk generated by different cases. Final data is a combination of Date,Time, Data and some strings.

Comment: okay, so regarding the german/english transform it might be the simplest to do a find/replace in your input file before even importing into matlab; that saves that completely for every processing run (i presume you want to work on the processing algorithm, thus the "overhead" will also become costly over time..)
otherwise, unless you have the chance to provide different input formats (binary etc) you wont get around parsing of strings into numbers, and that will always be expensive. the solution of @Adrian below would also be my best guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to try, it depends how well you know your data. str2double at it's core uses sscanf but does a lot of checking.

If your data is good then for step 1 create an anonymous function to do the replacement and conversion in one step using sscanf to skip the checks.

```
myStr2num = @(x) sscanf(strrep(x{1},',','.'),'%f'); 
Data_in = arrayfun(myStr2num ,Cell_in(:,2:end));
```

For step 2 there is an undocumented function called [sprintfc](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) which will generate a cell array from a numeric array, reportedly very quick.

This may speed up step 2 for you.

```
Data_out = sprintfc('%g',Data_in);
Data_out = strrep(Data_out,',','.');
```

Comment: Step 2 is speeding up the program by 15x times. Replace the dot by comma and vice versa in the last step. But still the same problem with the first one. I found a interesting article [sscanf and sprintf] [1] and look into the comments for sscanf and sprintf.                                                                                                                                     [1]: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-and-the-event-dispatch-thread-edt